# Сообщение в Google Chrome - Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/x-js:

Tags: google-chrome, warning

Всем, привет! Подскажите пожалуйста, почему Google Chrome выдает сообщение `Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/x-js:`, что она означает? В исходном файле content-type правильный. На этот счет нашел [такой ответ](http://scriptidy.com/resource-interpreted-as-script-but-transferred-with-mime-type-textplain.html), но у меня скрипты не подключается через php, а и да соответствено JS-скрипты не работают.

Comment: content-type: application/javascript - так у вас?

Comment: @ghost rider вы вот это имеете в виду `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

Comment: я имел ввиду при отправке header'a. Вы вообще не используете PHP?

Comment: нет, я не использую php, я еще в описании вопроса это написал

Comment: Надо добавить строчку AddType text/javascript, в .htaccess, если скрипт исполняется на чужом сервере, обращаться за помощью к админу

Comment: Да, скорее всего веб-сервер неправильно сконфигурирован.

Comment: спасибо за рекомендации! буду смотреть в чем причина